# Want information regarding terraform List type variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am declaring my list type variable as below

```
variable service_account_email {
  description = "The email of the service account for the instance template."
  default     = "default"
}

variable service_account_scopes {
  description = "List of scopes for the instance template service account"
  type        = "list"

  default = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
  ]
}
```

but while trying to use the variable as below getting error as mentioned below :

```
service_account {
    email  = "${var.service_account_email}"
    scopes = ["${var.service_account_scopes}"]
  }
```

> Error: Incorrect attribute value type
>
> on pure_testing\main.tf line 22, in resource
>   "google_compute_instance" "default":   22:     scopes =
>   ["${var.service_account_scopes}"]
>
> Inappropriate value for attribute "scopes": element 0: string
>   required.

If I am doing wrong , could you please help me to clarify the concept of list variables here in terraform.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass nested lists to the resource.

Remove the square brackets from the `scopes = ...` part and it should be fine.

Comment: getting error as below after removing []
Error: service_account: attribute supports 1 item maximum, config has 2 declared

Comment: You'd need to show your full config but that error sounds like you've declared the `service_account` block twice.

Comment: Yes , you are correct , I was declaring service_account 2 time , Thanks a lot for your help . One more help I need (could you please help me to understand concept of data in Terraform) , again Thanks a lot :)